# Winforms : control width larger on linux than windows

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, mono

I dev an Winforms app and want deploy it on raspbian with Mono. I use responsive class i found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1140717/A-Responsive-Design-Technique-for-WinForms#_articleTop)
When I launch it on windows device it works well but on linux the control width is larger so my window overflow my screen width.

Your help is welcome because i don't know why this happen.

app on windows screen :
[app on windows screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSaYo.png)

app on linux screen :
[app on linux screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny3Jp.png)

Comment: Most likely a DPI settings issue

Comment: Different OS issue. Fonts are different, a lot of things are different... nobody guarantees the results will be the same.

Comment: this will not happen if you use panels and the dock property. Never calculate and set dimension properties, let winforms handle it by using containers such as panels and the dock property

Comment: Probably your controls' container has its Autosize property set to Font, and the font used in the Linux machine has a wider kerning, thus the container adjusts its content and makes everything wider.

Comment: @GuidoG can I make a responsive design just with panels and dock property ? sure I will use it for my app but I thinks this way doesn't resize my control like responsive design ? If it is possible can you have a link for sample or tutorial ?

Comment: Using panels and the dock property is very easy to keep all controls on the correct place when resizing, but it will not do any scaling or resizing of controls. I have no experience in doing that in winforms

Comment: ok thanks you for this answer but I don't want resize my app, it runs in fullscreen that is why I'm using this responsive class to scale, resize and replace all my control according to resolution's screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments it's helped me to found a begin of solution I will share it with you.

First I change the property "AutoScaleMode" of my Form from "Font" to "None" like Jimi said. This tip help for the window width but my text label "Hello responsive world" still overflow because of the Linux's font. So I installed Microsoft's Font on Linux (sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts) and it's work fine now even if there still have a small shift.